# Как сверстать вот такой элемент

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, psd

Как можно сверстать такой элемент фотографии. на **Bootstrap**?

[image: tajem master]

Comment: Просто блоки, которые прижаты к левому краю?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.col-xs-2 {
  min-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:green"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:green"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:green"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```